# Como fazer join de datasets de classe "sf"?

Tags: r, join

```
library(sf)
library(rio)
library(tidyverse)
```

Reproduzindo os exemplos do `help` da função `sf::st_join()`:

```
a= st_sf(a = 1:3,
      geom = st_sfc(st_point(c(1,1)), 
                    st_point(c(2,2)),
                    st_point(c(3,3))))

b = st_sf(a = 11:14,
          geom = st_sfc(st_point(c(10,10)), 
                        st_point(c(2,2)), 
                        st_point(c(2,2)), 
                        st_point(c(3,3))))
```

```
> a
Simple feature collection with 3 features and 1 field
Geometry type: POINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 1 ymin: 1 xmax: 3 ymax: 3
CRS:           NA
  a        geom
1 1 POINT (1 1)
2 2 POINT (2 2)
3 3 POINT (3 3)
```

```
> b
Simple feature collection with 4 features and 1 field
Geometry type: POINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 2 ymin: 2 xmax: 10 ymax: 10
CRS:           NA
   a          geom
1 11 POINT (10 10)
2 12   POINT (2 2)
3 13   POINT (2 2)
4 14   POINT (3 3)
```

Adicionalmente, criei outros dois datasets que são cópias dos dois primeiros:

```
c = a
d = b
```

Quando tento fazer o `st_join()` para os datasets "**a**" e "**c**", o resultado é o mesmo dataset.
O que é esperado, já que são as mesmas geometrias.

```
st_join(a, c)

Simple feature collection with 3 features and 2 fields
Geometry type: POINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 1 ymin: 1 xmax: 3 ymax: 3
CRS:           NA
  a.x a.y        geom
1   1   1 POINT (1 1)
2   2   2 POINT (2 2)
3   3   3 POINT (3 3)
```

No entanto, quando tento fazer o mesmo com os datasets "**b**" e "**d**", o resultado é diferente:

```
st_join(b,d)

Simple feature collection with 6 features and 2 fields
Geometry type: POINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 2 ymin: 2 xmax: 10 ymax: 10
CRS:           NA
    a.x a.y          geom
1    11  11 POINT (10 10)
2    12  12   POINT (2 2)
2.1  12  13   POINT (2 2)
3    13  12   POINT (2 2)
3.1  13  13   POINT (2 2)
4    14  14   POINT (3 3)
```

O resultado não deveria ser o mesmo dataset "b"?

Essa dúvida surgiu, na verdade, quando estava trabalhando com [esse dataset](https://github.com/cordeiroitamar/duvida_st_join/blob/main/dataset.xlsx)

Depois de carregar o dataset:

```
dataset_raw <- import("dataset.xlsx", setclass = "tibble")

head(dataset_raw)

# A tibble: 6 x 3
     v1 longitude latitude
  <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
1    40     -44.8    -15.3
2    66     -44.8    -15.3
3    56     -44.8    -15.3
4    33     -44.8    -15.3
5    53     -44.8    -15.3
6    90     -44.8    -15.3
```

... e de convertê-lo para a classe "sf":

```
dataset_sf_1 <- dataset_raw %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("longitude","latitude"), crs = 4674)

head(dataset_sf_1)

Simple feature collection with 6 features and 1 field
Geometry type: POINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -44.82357 ymin: -15.28923 xmax: -44.82344 ymax: -15.28918
Geodetic CRS:  SIRGAS 2000
# A tibble: 6 x 2
     v1              geometry
  <dbl>           <POINT [°]>
1    40 (-44.82357 -15.28918)
2    66 (-44.82351 -15.28921)
3    56 (-44.82351 -15.28921)
4    33 (-44.82351 -15.28921)
5    53 (-44.82351 -15.28921)
6    90 (-44.82344 -15.28923)
```

... criei uma cópia do mesmo:

```
dataset_sf_2 <- dataset_sf_1
```

Foi então que verifiquei que embora cada um tenha **2699** linhas (já que um é a cópia do outro)...

```
dim(dataset_sf_1)

[1] 2699    2



dim(dataset_sf_2)

[1] 2699    2
```

... quando faço o `st_join` a quantidade de linhas pula para **17147**

```
st_join(dataset_sf_1, dataset_sf_2)

Simple feature collection with 17147 features and 2 fields
Geometry type: POINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -44.82357 ymin: -15.31984 xmax: 0 ymax: 0
Geodetic CRS:  SIRGAS 2000
# A tibble: 17,147 x 3
    v1.x              geometry  v1.y
 * <dbl>           <POINT [°]> <dbl>
 1    40 (-44.82357 -15.28918)    40
 2    66 (-44.82351 -15.28921)    66
 3    66 (-44.82351 -15.28921)    56
 4    66 (-44.82351 -15.28921)    33
 5    66 (-44.82351 -15.28921)    53
 6    56 (-44.82351 -15.28921)    66
 7    56 (-44.82351 -15.28921)    56
 8    56 (-44.82351 -15.28921)    33
 9    56 (-44.82351 -15.28921)    53
10    33 (-44.82351 -15.28921)    66
# ... with 17,137 more rows
```

Em suma: como fazer adequadamente o join de datasets do tipo "sf"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note que `b` possui dois pontos com mesmas coordenadas (pontos 2 e 3), mas com atributos diferentes (valores do campo *a*):

```
   a          geom
1 11 POINT (10 10)
2 12   POINT (2 2)
3 13   POINT (2 2)
4 14   POINT (3 3)
```

Ao fazer a união de b e sua cópia usando o algoritmo padrão (`st_intersects`), são criados pontos com as combinações dos valores. Note os valores de a.x e a.y dos pontos 2, 2.1, 3 e 3.1:

```
    a.x a.y          geom
1    11  11 POINT (10 10)
2    12  12   POINT (2 2)
2.1  12  13   POINT (2 2)
3    13  12   POINT (2 2)
3.1  13  13   POINT (2 2)
4    14  14   POINT (3 3)
```

Pode usar a opção `largest = TRUE` para manter apenas os valores maiores:

```
st_join(b, d, largest = TRUE)
#> Simple feature collection with 4 features and 2 fields
#> geometry type:  POINT
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: 2 ymin: 2 xmax: 10 ymax: 10
#> CRS:            NA
#>   a.x a.y          geom
#> 1  11  11 POINT (10 10)
#> 2  12  12   POINT (2 2)
#> 3  13  12   POINT (2 2)
#> 4  14  14   POINT (3 3)
```

Ou indicar um algoritmo mais adequado para sua situação, por exemplo `st_overlaps`:

```
st_join(b, d, st_overlaps)
#> Simple feature collection with 4 features and 2 fields
#> geometry type:  POINT
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: 2 ymin: 2 xmax: 10 ymax: 10
#> CRS:            NA
#>   a.x a.y          geom
#> 1  11  NA POINT (10 10)
#> 2  12  NA   POINT (2 2)
#> 3  13  NA   POINT (2 2)
#> 4  14  NA   POINT (3 3)
```

A melhor opção depende dos seus dados e de seus objetivos. Veja os Detalhes na ajuda de `sf::geos_binary_pred`.

Comment: Perfeito @Carlos Eduardo Lagosta. Muito obrigado pelos esclarecimentos